# Create a matrix of scatterplots (pairs() equivalent) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

Is it possible to plot a matrix of scatter plots with `ggplot2`, using `ggplot`'s nice features like mapping additional factors to color, shape etc. and adding smoother?

I am thinking about something similar to the `base` function `pairs`.

Comment: Also check out ggally

Comment: Ah, I didn't see your comment there hadley. I made my answer CW so as not to steal your cred :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You might want to try plotmatrix:

```
  library(ggplot2)
  data(mtcars)
  plotmatrix(mtcars[,1:3])
```

to me mpg (first column in mtcars) should not be a factor. I haven't checked it, but there's no reason why it should be one. However I get a scatter plot :)

---

**Note:** For future reference, the `plotmatrix()` function has been replaced by the `ggpairs()` function from the `GGally` package as @naught101 suggests [in another response below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12047554) to this question.

Comment: I could not get faceting to work on this problem, it seems it requires factors on the right hand side of the formula.. Or could you give me a minimal example?

Comment: Anyone know how to add colour?  I don't seem to be able to get this https://gist.github.com/1405150 to work

Comment: The first part of this answer is wrong, and cause for confusion. You can't do pairs plots with faceting: you can only do y by x plots, and group them by factors. In other words, with faceting you have the same x and y on each sub-plot; with pairs, you have a different x on each column, and a different y on each row.

Comment: For future reference, the `plotmatrix()` function has been replaced by the `ggpairs()` function from the `GGally` package as @naught101 suggests in another response to this question.

Comment: Y'all down voters realize that this answer is almost 5 years old? Do you want me to delete / edit this answer?

Comment: @MattBannert added the comment to your post to make it more visible, I could understand the downvoters if had skipped reading the comments. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 259):

I keep wanting to do this, but plotmatrix is crap. Hadley [recommends](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/158) using the [GGally package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GGally/index.html) instead. It has a function, [ggpairs](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=GGally:ggpairs) that is a vastly improved pairs plot (lets you use non-continuous variables in your data frames). It plots different plots in each square, depending on the variable types:

```
library(GGally)
ggpairs(iris, aes(colour = Species, alpha = 0.4))
```

[image]

Comment: This is really great. It is worth noting that any `colour` variable has to be a factor; spent 45 minutes figuring that one out.

Comment: +1. By the way, do you know how to adjust the plots so that the labels are shown in their entirety and not overlapping?

Comment: Is there any way to plot these correlation matrices without pairs?For example I need to plot the first column versus every other column.ggpairs gives very possible pair.For e.g I have 10 columns and it gives me 10 *10 =100.But I want 1st column vs other 9 only

Comment: @Rgeek: you could `melt` the dataframe using the variable you are interested in as an id variable, and then facet by the other variables.

Comment: So now my data is in the required format with 3 columns.First being the id ,second being the variable and 3rd being the value of the variable.The first is repeated according to the number of variables which are 10.I can do ggplot but not sure how to do ggpairs on this as I need 10 correlation plots.

Comment: Don't use ggpairs, just use ggplot2 normally, like `ggplot(data, aes(x=id, y=value)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(.~variable)`. I'm assuming you're talking about scatter plots when you say "correlation plot", because I've never heard of that otherwise.

Comment: got following warning and no color in the plot. `In ggpairs(iris, colour = "Species", alpha = 0.4) :
  Extra arguments: 'colour', 'alpha' are being ignored.  If these are meant to be aesthetics, submit them using the 'mapping' variable within ggpairs with ggplot2::aes or ggplot2::aes_string.`
any idea how to make it work with the newest ggplot2?..

Comment: @JimGreen  `GGally::ggpairs(iris, aes(colour = Species, alpha=0.4))`

Answer (score 22):

If one wants to obtain a `ggplot` object (not `ggmatrix` as in case of `ggpairs()`), the solution is to melt the data twice, then `ggplot` with facetting. `facet_wrap` would be better than `facet_grid` in limiting the plotted area, given the `scales = 'free'` parameter is supplied.

```
require(ggplot2) 
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)

gatherpairs <- function(data, ..., 
                        xkey = '.xkey', xvalue = '.xvalue',
                        ykey = '.ykey', yvalue = '.yvalue',
                        na.rm = FALSE, convert = FALSE, factor_key = FALSE) {
  vars <- quos(...)
  xkey <- enquo(xkey)
  xvalue <- enquo(xvalue)
  ykey <- enquo(ykey)
  yvalue <- enquo(yvalue)

  data %>% {
    cbind(gather(., key = !!xkey, value = !!xvalue, !!!vars,
                 na.rm = na.rm, convert = convert, factor_key = factor_key),
          select(., !!!vars)) 
  } %>% gather(., key = !!ykey, value = !!yvalue, !!!vars,
               na.rm = na.rm, convert = convert, factor_key = factor_key)
}

iris %>% 
  gatherpairs(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width) %>% {
  ggplot(., aes(x = .xvalue, y = .yvalue, color = Species)) +
      geom_point() + 
      geom_smooth(method = 'lm') +
      facet_wrap(.xkey ~ .ykey, ncol = length(unique(.$.ykey)), scales = 'free', labeller = label_both) +
      scale_color_brewer(type = 'qual')
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try [scatterPlotMatrix](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterPlotMatrix/vignettes/introduction-to-scatterplotmatrix.html). It's very flexible and produces nice looking interactive charts.

```
library(scatterPlotMatrix)
scatterPlotMatrix(iris, zAxisDim = "Species")
```

[image]